# Django manage.py runserver verbosity

Tags: django

Is there a way to make the runserver command completely quiet or just display errors like 404 or 500 ??
verbosity option has no effect on it...

Comment: Are you trying to remove noise in your command prompt?

Comment: Just checking. Have you tried --verbosity=0

Answer (score 15):

You can now set the verbosity with the `verbosity` flag:

```
./manage.py runserver --verbosity 0
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-verbosity)

Comment: However, runserver (1.7) doesn't seem to comply with the verbosity 0 argument. I'm getting the exact same output.

Comment: @JuanXarg it should : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---verbosity

Comment: Django runserver ignores verbosity or traceback option. See this discussion over this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15132

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to make the command less verbose with options.  You can however pipe the output someplace where you don't need to care about it.  On Linux/OS X/*nix you can pipe the output to /dev/null with something like:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver > /dev/null
```

The equivalent on windows would be something like:

```
python manage.py runserver > NUL
```

One last note:  If you are seeking to suppress the output as a matter of preference in your development environment, awesome!  This should work for you.  If you are seeking to do this for almost any other reason, it's probably a sign that you are using the dev server for something which you shouldn't.  "./manage.py runserver" should never be used for ***anything*** other than local development.

Comment: +1 for "runserver should never be used for anything other than local development"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pull it off by disabling logging in general, as I am launching my application as a subprocess of different application. [Documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging)

This blocks all logs including `Watching for file changes with StatReloader`.

And all logs of this kind: `[31/Jul/2020 20:42:17] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6641`.

By adding this to my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
}
```