# How to get django runserver to stop logging to console in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

here is my are my logger settings

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'handlers': {
        # Send all messages to console
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
         '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I have configured logging in Django, but my logs are drowned in the continous GET, POST, PUT requests my frontend generates
i.e i dont want to see logs from django like this

```
[08/Jul/2015 11:05:59] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 910
```

only my logs from

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Hello world')
```

is there a way to letrunserver not to display requests and only show logs only from my loggers

I forgot to mention this in in pycharm

this has no effect in additional options

```
--verbosity 0
```

this in additional options

```
 > dev/null
```

gives this error

```
CommandError: Usage is runserver [optional port number, or ipaddr:port]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django manage.py runserver verbosity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754409/django-manage-py-runserver-verbosity)

Comment: Make a management command with this https://gist.github.com/nwjlyons/7487f9943311f038cd4a459e03faba4b

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [Logging settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/) to do that.

Django has number of default [Loggers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#django-s-logging-extensions), you can change the handler for whatever logger you want. Maybe if you want to stop it forever make it `'handlers': ['null']`.

Reading documentation would be very helpful for you for more information about managing your log.

Comment: 'handlers': ['null'] would stop all looging, i want only console logs from my own logging

Comment: @MrMixin I thought you want to silent it at all. If so, you can set the loggers you want for every single logger, and don't include console in any of them !

Comment: About you special loggers (when you use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, name of the logger is the path of the current file
So you need to configure it in logging settings, and add console to the handlers.